# How to know java or java run time version on a computer

Tags: java, java-8, jvm

I have just started learning basics of java for my ultimate goal to learn Android. So I installed latest version of java from [here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk8-downloads-2133151.html). In .Net world I've used commands like `ClrVer` to know what all CLR versions are currently installed on the current machine.

I'm on Windows 7 and I checked my control panel to see the installation which happened. It shows the installer version to be`8.0.1010.13` as shown in the snapshot below:

[image]

But that way I got bit more confused as I'm not sure if Java version, JRE version, Java Virtual Machine (JVM) version , Java Development Kit (JDK) version and the installer version (shown in the control panel snapshot above) would be same or different by any chance.

**Is there any setting, registry, file properties or command with the help of which I can get to know the exact or complete version of java which got installed**?

Also in .Net world the version of Language (e.g. C#), Run time (CLR) and .Net framework are completely independent and they might not be same at any given point of time. Is that exactly the same in Java world as well? **Is it a single unified version per release which describes them all**?

Comment: `java --version`, `javac --version`

Comment: It also depends on which java installation your PATH Variable points

Comment: there maybe more than one JRE (Java Runtime) and/or JDK (java Development Kit) install as pointed to by JAVA_HOME - use java --version, javac --version

Answer (score 4):

In addition to using `java -version` to get the runtime, you could also use `java.version` (a system property) to get it. Something like,

```
System.out.println(System.getProperty("java.version"));
```

Comment: That will just show the version of the currently *running* JVM. That is not similar to *"to know what **all** CLR versions are currently installed"*. To list installed Java versions, you'd likely have to look in the Windows Registry, bearing in mind that there may be Java versions on the hard drive(s) that aren't "installed", and hence will not show in the registry. For full list, you'd have to scan hard drive(s), e.g. for `java.exe` or `jvm.dll`.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do this from code, then you should use `System` class:

```
System.getProperty("java.version");
```

If lets say your program will be dependant on a given version.

You can find out more on what properties for the JVM you can get here: https://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-list-all-system-properties-key-and-value-in-java/
Just in your code output the `System.getProperty(wantedProperty)`

Hope this clears a bit on what you have in mind, if I understand it correctly

Answer (score 0):

I believe your system variables hold JAVA_HOME and JDK_HOME which tell Windows where to look for Java.  Your JDK and Java can be of different versions, and you can even have many versions of each on your machine.  They run according to the above mentioned variables and your PATH system variable.

I think what you are seeing above is for Java runtime, not the SDK.  If you open a Windows prompt and do "java -v" it will tell you your runtime version and "javac -version" your JDK version.

Answer (score 0):

When you download a JDK, you’ll get a bundle of Java Language, JRE, JVM, etc. all in a matching version. Some technical artifacts (e.g. the JVM) may have another internal version number, but that’s nothing you need to care for, since usually, there are no separate downloads for, e.g. a newer JVM, but rather, the next version of the JVM will be bundled with the next JDK version.

Further, the Java *programming language* doesn’t have minor version numbers. So here, the Java language has version 8 and all JDKs with the same major version are supposed to implement that language as specified. Of course, the `javac` compiler shipped with a JDK may have bugs, but the bugfixed version of the next JDK update release still is intended to support all JREs with the major version 8.

Note that despite its name, updating a JDK implies replacing it entirely with a new version.